# What files are pushed to a Docker Hub?

Tags: docker

I am creating and image to reuse in my projects which I want to push to Docker Hub.

I initially thought that I just had to make a folder, put a right Dockerfile with some additional files like configs and push it.

Then I realized that I also had to create an image based on this Dockerfile first.

So, I suppose, Docker Hub keeps the image that I created locally? Thus, images can be quite large, like gigabytes?

Please shed light on what's exactly is being pushed when I run `docker push name/repo`.

Answer (score 0):

A good start to understanding is checking out Docker's [overview of images and containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/).

In summary - Docker is built on a [layered filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS).  Each command in a `Dockerfile`  adds, writes or modifies files, which are stored as changes to the layer below.  This process makes it easy to re-use base containers (because the layers are not modified) - and efficiently rebuild images when commands have not changed.

And those filesystem layers (plus other metadata that make up an image) are what is pushed to Docker Hub.

> Thus, images can be quite large, like gigabytes?

A small Dockerfile often creates a much larger image, so why not upload just the Dockerfile?  I think the reason is *consistency*.  Often a Dockerfile starts with `FROM debian` or `FROM alpine` or maybe with a version tag like `FROM python:3.5`. But when the image behind that tag changes, you will build different images from the same Dockerfile.  At some point a build could break an application, or cause subtle bugs.  But with all the filesystem layers cacged  on Docker Hub, the same binary image runs every time.